# Lambda in Private VPC taking long time to use S3 API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I created a lambda function to move an object from one S3 bucket to another. The lambda function exists in a VPC.

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

const sourceBucket = "source-bucket";
const destinationBucket = "destination-bucket";

const copyObjectAsync = (params) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  s3.copyObject(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    else resolve(data);
  });
});

const deleteObjectAsync = (params) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  s3.deleteObject(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    else resolve(data);
  });
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const objectKey = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
  try {
    console.log(`Start moving: ${objectKey}`);
    const copySource = "/" + sourceBucket + "/" + objectKey;
    await copyObjectAsync({
      Bucket: destinationBucket,
      CopySource: copySource,
      Key: objectKey,
      ContentType: 'application/x-gzip',
    });
    console.log(`Copied successfully - ${objectKey}`);
    await deleteObjectAsync({
      Bucket: sourceBucket,
      Key: objectKey,
    });
    console.log(`Deleted successfully - ${objectKey}`);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code === 'NoSuchKey') {
      console.log(`${objectKey} already moved`);
      return;
    }
    console.log(err.stack.substr(0, 200));
    // Throw to retry?
    throw err;
  }
}
```

I know the S3 endpoints, S3 policies, IAM role, etc have been set up correctly because this function does work but I noticed there's a massive delay when calling `s3.copyObject` or `s3.deleteObject`. For example, in the execution below, there's a ~4 minute wait time to move a test file with "hello world" in it.

CloudWatch Logs

```
09:39:52 START RequestId: <GUID> Version: $LATEST
09:39:52 2019-11-10T09:39:52.676Z <GUID> INFO Start moving: source-bucket/input/tenbatsu_copy_files_2.txt
09:44:16 2019-11-10T09:44:16.017Z <GUID> INFO Copied successfully - source-bucket/input/tenbatsu_copy_files_2.txt
09:44:16 2019-11-10T09:44:16.220Z <GUID> INFO Deleted successfully - source-bucket/input/tenbatsu_copy_files_2.txt
09:44:16 END RequestId: <GUID>
09:44:16 REPORT RequestId: <GUID> Duration: 263579.63 ms Billed Duration: 263600 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 99 MB Init Duration: 380.26 ms
```

2+ minutes to copy and then times out before deleting

```
09:56:35 START RequestId: <GUID> Version: $LATEST
09:56:35 2019-11-10T09:56:35.363Z <GUID> INFO Start moving: source-bucket/input/tenbatsu_copy_files_3.txt
09:58:46 2019-11-10T09:58:46.380Z <GUID> INFO Copied successfully - source-bucket/input/tenbatsu_copy_files_3.txt
10:01:35 END RequestId: <GUID>
10:01:35 REPORT RequestId: <GUID> Duration: 300100.16 ms Billed Duration: 300000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 99 MB Init Duration: 369.49 ms
10:01:35 2019-11-10T10:01:35.460Z <GUID> Task timed out after 300.10 seconds
```

What could the issue be?

Comment: Are you sure you're not copying a large file? Any differences when doing `getObject` followed by `putObject`? Also note that you can do `await s3.copyObject(params).promise()` instead of creating wrapper functions.

Comment: Have you tested this outside of VPC to see if that makes a difference? Are the buckets in the same region? What size are the files? PS there's no need to promisify AWS SDK calls. Just use `s3.copyObject(params).promise()`.

Comment: @Jarmod
Turns out that our VPC ACL was configured with these ephemeral ports open: 32768-61000.
After AWS implemented this change https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/
the timeouts started happening. I opened up ports 1024-65535 and now it seems to be working okay.